# improving build time - teamcity/maven - fat jar

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, teamcity

We have a pom file that contains a large amount of java components. We build this pom in TC and then deploy to our unix box. I noticed that in TC for every dependancy in the pom it goes away to artifactory, downloads and expands. That is fine however, if the dependancy is the same version, it still goes away and downloads.

Is there a way that i can set this in tc/maven build settings so it only downloads if there has been a change in dependancy version within the pom. This would save us time, however that being said - we would still need to contain all the components. So idealy, the first ever build would download all components and then every other subsequent build, we would only download changes and they would be merged them with unchanged dependancies from the previous build.

Is this possible? if someone could point me in the right direction.Thanks